# How is returning a subtype in a method expecting a supertype called covariance?

Tags: java, covariance

Wikipedia defines `covariance` as

> converting from wider (Animals) to narrower (Cats).

but in languages like `Java`, return type covariance is defined as assigning a subtype to a supertype like :

```
public Animal getAnimal(){
   return new Cat();
}
```

Here, we are assigning a subtype to a supertype but according to the `Wikipedia` definition, covariance is assigning a supertype to subtype. How can I reconcile the two ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of what having covariant return types means.

It is only relevant when you override a method, it does not refer to the types used in return statements or what the caller expects from a method.
Covariant return type means you can override a method in a subtype and change the return type during overriding (giving it a narrower return type than the method in the supertype).

Example:

```
public class SuperType {
  public Animal getAnimal() { ... }
}

public class SubType extends SuperType {
  public Cat getAnimal() { ... }
}
```

Here the definition of Wikipedia matches.

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) confirms this in [section 8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3) (c.f. [example 8.4.8.3-1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3)).

Note that for method parameters, Java requires contravariant types. If `getAnimal` took a parameter of type `Animal` in `SuperType`, the class `SubType` could not narrow this parameter to `Cat`, but could widen it to (e.g.) `Object`.

Comment: I understand it in the sense you explained..So.. what the others have answered is not the real meaning then.. right..or their interpretation is not correct ?

Comment: @Daud Yes, I think that what Mike and Lesstat wrote is not the real meaning of covariant return types.

Answer (score 1):

The general term "co-variant" implies two entities that can vary along an axis, and it states that the entities are related such that when one makes a *zig*, the other also makes a *zig*. In contrast, "contra-variance" would mean that when one makes a *zig*, the other makes a *zag*.

Specifically, in type theory, two types are co-variant if, when we narrow down one, the other is also narrowed down.

Applying this to Java return types, as we step from a class to its subclass, the return type of a method can step the same way: from class to subclass.

Contrast this with what would be meaningful for method parameters: stepping from class to subclass, the parameter type might step from class to *superclass*. This feature does not exist in Java, but if it did, this would be the way it would work.

Answer (score 0):

The definition for covariance of wikipedia as you stated, is the same as what the Java function is doing. The function returns an animal, but in this case, it narrows it down to a cat (hence more variaty).

You are probably going wrong at "according to the Wikipedia definition, covariance is assigning a supertype to subtype". As this is not the same as converting from wider (Animals) to narrower (Cats), but exactly the opposite.

```
//This is covariance, as you go from wider, to narrower
Animal someAnimal = new Animal();
someAnimal = getAnimal(); //now someAnimal is a cat, as by your code example.
```

Comment: I am sorry.. I am not able to get it.. I am converting from Cat (narrower) to Animal (wider).. its the opposite of covariance..

Comment: Your function can return any animal, but it is narrowing down to a cat instead. What is does is the same as the definition of covariance. What the function is doing to the cat is not the same as what the function means for the code that uses this function.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe try to see it the following way:

The method is saying: "I'll give you an Animal"
if it gives you a Cat afterwards it has not lied. It goes form the wider to the narrower type.